# Why does preconditioned CG converge faster than basic CG

Tags: algorithm, numerical-methods

Is there any intuitive explanation that why preconditioned conjugate gradient (CG)algorithm converges faster than basic CG algorithm.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, it is about linear algebra.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Are pure computer science questions on-topic here?  This, to me, is a pure numerical-methods question, not about linear algebra, but about the theory of solving linear algebra problems with computers.

Comment: *Are pure computer science questions on-topic here?* Generally not and there's another site in the SE universe for them.  But I wouldn't classify this as a pure cs question either.

Answer (score 1):

Conjugate gradient is equivalent to preconditioned conjugate gradient with the identity matrix for the preconditioner. If you could use the matrix itself for the preconditioner, then PCG would converge in one iteration. The hope is, by using a preconditioner that is "more alike" the matrix than the identity but easier to solve against than the matrix itself, then PCG will be faster than CG in solving to equivalent quality.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://www.math.iit.edu/~fass/477577_Chapter_16.pdf) provides I think a satisfactory explanation.
Basically, the rate of convergence of the conjugate gradient method depends on `sqrt(kappa(A))`, ie, the condition number of the matrix to solve.  So what you do is you choose a matrix `M` such that, `kappa(inv(M) * A) < kappa(A)` and then solve the system `inv(M) * A * x = inv(M) * b`.  This will take less iterations to solve because the condition number of the matrix to solve is less than the original.